# Why is my Angular Node.js application uploading images to S3 with � symbols while Postman uploads them correctly?

Tags: java, node.js, angular, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I know that when I post an image through Postman, the image shows up as you'd expect. However, when it's uploaded through my application using, from what I can tell, the same headers/qualifications, the image gets shredded or converted into an unreadable format with the diamond question mark symbols. Why is this happening? How can I prevent this? Why?

HTML:

```
<h1>File Upload</h1>
<input type="file" name="uploadImages" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
<button mat-raised-button type="button" mat-button color="primary" (click)="onUpload()">Upload</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ServiceContext } from 'src/app/services/service-context/service.context';

@Component ({
    selector: 'upload-images',
    templateUrl: './upload-images.html',
    styleUrls: ['./upload-images.css']
})

export class UploadImagesComponent {
    selectedFile: File = null;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        private context: ServiceContext) {}

    onFileSelected(event) {
        this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
    }

    onUpload() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
        this.http.post('/storage/uploadFile', formData)
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
}
```

Java Controller(Springboot):

```
package inno.garage.june19.bucket;

import inno.garage.june19.bucket.AmazonClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/storage")
public class BucketController {

    private AmazonClient amazonClient;

    @Autowired
    BucketController(AmazonClient amazonClient) {
        this.amazonClient = amazonClient;
    }

    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestPart(value = "Image") MultipartFile file) {
        return this.amazonClient.uploadFile(file);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deleteFile")
    public String deleteFile(@RequestPart(value = "url") String fileUrl) {
        return this.amazonClient.deleteFileFromS3Bucket(fileUrl);
    }
}
```

Java Service:

```
package inno.garage.june19.bucket;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

@Service
public class AmazonClient {

    private AmazonS3 s3client;

    @Value("${amazonProperties.endpointUrl}")
    private String endpointUrl;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initializeAmazon() {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(this.accessKey, this.secretKey);
        this.s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    }

    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        String fileUrl = "";
        try {
            File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
            String fileName = generateFileName(multipartFile);
            fileUrl = endpointUrl + "/" + bucketName + "/" + fileName;
            uploadFileTos3bucket(fileName, file);
            file.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileUrl;
    }

    private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
    }

    private String generateFileName(MultipartFile multiPart) {
        return new Date().getTime() + "-" + multiPart.getOriginalFilename().replace(" ", "_");
    }

    private void uploadFileTos3bucket(String fileName, File file) {
        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file)
                .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    }

    public String deleteFileFromS3Bucket(String fileUrl) {
        String fileName = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        s3client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName));
        return "Successfully deleted";
    }

}
```

[This is a screencap of my terminal in VS Code after clicking upload in my web app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of6Fg.png)
[Screencap of my S3 bucket. When clicking the url generated for the image in S3, it says "The image 'Image URL' cannot be displayed because it contains errors."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge94E.png)

Comment: Can you look at your browser's dev tools and open the network tab and tell us what you see when you post the image? Like Headers, Body, etc?

Comment: https://imgur.com/w5IMpc0
When I click on the Edit and Resend button: https://imgur.com/XzXgdkk

Thank you for looking at this. I have been working on this same issue for about a week now. There has to be a reason why it isn't working in the app and IS in Postman.

Comment: You are not encoding your image, are you? You might have to perform a base64 and send it to the controller

Comment: If I'm encoding it, it isn't on purpose. If I base 64 encode the image before sending it to S3, will the image be saved that way in S3? I'm trying to send these images in an email later on in this application and I had a problem before where S3 was storing images as a base64 encoded string and when the images where sent via email, they wouldn't show up because most email clients don't support base64